# Trouble selecting time range in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just have a quick question, I am doing a cab booking system. I am finding troubles selecting the reservations within the next 2 hours in SQL. I don't need the whole reservation to appear when i select all, I only want within two hours from the time I run the query.

```
$query= "select Booking_No,
    Email_Address,
    Customer_Name,
    Passenger_Name,
    Phone_No,
    concat(Unit_Number,'/', Street_Number,' ', Street_Name,',', Suburb) as   Unit_Number,
    Destination_Suburb,
    Pickup_Date,
    Pickup_Time from Booking1
    where status = 'false'
    and
    (Pickup_Time >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%h:00:00') and 
    Pickup_Time <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%h') + interval 2 hour)";
```

Comment: So what happens when you run this?

Comment: when I run this code I get the bookings within the same hour that we are at. e.g. lets say now its 10:30pm. When i run it, I will get all the bookings from 10:00pm, until 10:59pm, and not within the next 2 hours as i want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'BETWEEN' clause in your WHERE clause.

```
WHERE status = 'false' AND Pickup_Time BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

NOW() returns a date/time object, DATE_ADD() returns a date/time object. As long as your Pickup_Time is a date/time object, this will work like a treat!